# Move file via Microsoft Graph and create new version if file already exists

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Moving a file without additional parameters fails when a file with the same name already exists in the target directory.
We can use additional data and set conflict behavior replace, but then the old file gets replaced completely.

```cs
var driveItem = new DriveItem()
{
    ParentReference = new ItemReference
    {
        Id = newFolderId
    },
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior", "replace" }
    }
};
```

What we want/need is a way to move the file and on conflict add it as a new version of the old file so that all old conflict files are still accessible via the version history.

Is that possible somehow?

BR Matthias

Comment: I would rather check if the file with the same name already exists and in that case I would update "old" file with a new content (from moved file) and delete the source file. If the file with the same name doesn't exist I would you move function

Comment: I'm afraid you have to combine the move api and the get or list api together to realize your requirement, I mean that you check the target folder if it contains the file first and if it contains, then you can name the file like xx(1).txt before moving the file.